# for with a variable list

Tags: python, for-loop

```
from random import shuffle
k = 1000
T = 0
while k!=0:
    ludzie = [i for i in range(1000)]
    plaszcze = [i for i in range(1000)]
    shuffle(plaszcze)
    for value in range(k):
        if ludzie[value]==plaszcze[value]:
            k = k - 1
            del(ludzie[value])
            del(plaszcze[value])
    T = T + 1
print(T)
```

I'd like the first time I've done the loop, the people list was an updated list with del used earlier, the same for the coat list. Then when we use the loop the second time, it would compare the updated people with coats.

And unfortunately an error pops up.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 9, in <module>
if ludzie[value]==plaszcze[value]:
IndexError: list index out of range.
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your algorithm is wrong. According to your code, no matter what, the wile loop would generate  two new lists every time, till `k` equals 0. But your updates of two lists in `for` loop -- deleting item when `if` condition meets -- would not be kept. By the way, which one is people list? You'd better come up with explicit names next time. It would be helpful for answers.

Answer (score 0):

that makes sense. imagine this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [3, 2, 1]

for i in range(3):
    if a[i] == b[i]:
       del a[i]
       del b[i]
```

what happens when `i == 2`? answer, you try to access `a[2]` which no longer exists because you've shortened the list.

the thing is that you don't even need to delete these values. it serves no purpose other than to break your code. get rid of the 2 `del`s and it'll be fine

Comment: Only, just after the first loop is done, if ludzie[i] = plaszcze[i], then a list of plaszcze and ludzie without these 999 indices will be created, and it is to be checked during the second loop.

Comment: that is not what your algo is doing at all. you're always creating lists of 1000 elements

Comment: unfortunately i can't, because i don't understand what problem you're actually trying to solve.